# Email upstream job artifact in jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, artifact, upstream-branch

I have two jenkins jobs - JobA(upstream) and JobB(downstream). JobA generates the artifact TestReport.zip. I want to take TestReport.zip artifact in JobB and send it as an attachment in an email sent from JobB. I tried copy artifact plug in, but no luck. Can somebody please help with some steps how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing issue to passing TestReport.zip  to Job B or facing issue to send email from Job B. I am assuming, you are facing issue to pass artifact to job B. As copy artifact plugin you tried and not worked, there is some alternative, you can try. So if both job A and Job B are running from same jenkins slave, then you can store artifact in some common place from where Job B can also access that and Job B can copy that from own workspace and initiate email using that as attachment.  Please refer this article on how to pass parameter from one job to another.
https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/jenkins-related-articles/jenkins-configuration/jenkins-passing-a-parameter-from-one-job-to-another/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, i tried to pass like 'Report=src/main/resources/TestReport.zip'  in predefined parameters in JOBA and tried to access using $Report in attachment section of Editable email notification JOBB but no luck. though i get the email i dont see JOBA report in the email

Comment: Hi, are you using any plugin? If not you can use this plugin named https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/. Latest version has the ability to send attachment with email.

Comment: Yes I am using editable email notification plugin, through which I am able to email the attachment in same job that is JOBA, but not in the downstream job JOBB

Comment: Can you print the value of $Report in jobB to check if that paremeter is passing correctly from Job A?